# BulkLoader -export_transform

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have created web application using java.I wantted to download data from appengine datastroe so that I am using BulkLoader concept.

In my project I designed entity as follows

```
@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private Long school_id;

@Basic

private String schoolname;
```

After that I tried to download data so that I created bulkloader configuration file .It created successfully but I that default auto generated bulkloade.yaml file I have one problem(i.E)export-transform convert Primary key into string, but I need Long datatype how to achieve this.

The content of bulkloader file is

```
- kind: School

  connector: csv

  property_map:

    - property: __key__

      external_name: key

      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: schoolname

      external_name: schoolname
```

How to solve this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, you should accept more answers to improve your chances of getting any.

Answer (score 0):

Try `export_transform: datastore.Key.name`

Comment: I had tried this one also but it shows this error message TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found