# Bulkloader: How to define the transform.create_foreign_key() as int?

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

In my app, when I create a User object, the id is integer. `(id=23001)`

```
- kind: User
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

I have auto generated the bulkloader above, and when I delete the User and reupload it through the bulkloader, the id is no longer an integer. It is now `name=23001`

In order to enforce this, I came up with this idea:

```
- kind: User
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
      import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(int)
```

Now the import is set as integer and indeed I get a `id=23001` again.

The actual problem is the other class that uses a foreignkey on User:

```
- kind: AuthProvider
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: user_key
      external_name: user_key
      # Type: Key Stats: 1 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('User')
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

The field `user_key` is generated as string again instead of integer. (name=23001)
which means the keys are no longer the same, which is very bad.

What can I do, to make `user_key` to become id=xxx instead of name=xxx ?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('User', key_is_id=True)`